# Conversion between signed integer and unsigned integer

Tags: c++, casting, standards, unsigned-integer

If I cast an unsigned integer to a signed integer then cast back, am I guaranteed to get the original value? For example, does this function always return `true` for any `x` on any platform according to the C++ standard?

```
bool f(unsigned int x)
{
    return x == static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<int>(x));
}
```

What about this one?

```
bool g(int x)
{
    return x == static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned int>(x));
}
```

Comment: @sleeptightpupper I've made a mistake in my code. Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: I wasn't asking about that. I'm asking for what interval of values you're worried about. i.e, a negative value for `f` will obviously underflow so you will obviously not get the same value back.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper - you should try this with negative values yourself. You'll be shocked and surprised at the results.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `f(-1)` gives me `4294967295`. I don't find that very surprising. Either way, it's "undefined behavior".

Comment: @sleeptightpupper I've modified my code before my first comment, please notice that.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper It's not undefined behavior, it is implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @EFanZh use your debugger and watch the values change / or not change. That should answer your question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ["If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined."](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#4)

Comment: So, what have you tried?  or perhaps, what were the results of either test?  Did you cout a table of the results of static_cast<>?  I suppose there are 8 tests ... both directions ... MAX, MIN, 0, ... etc.  What did you find out?

Comment: @sleeptightpupper - how could f(-1) possibly give you that, when it computes a comparison operation, which is a boolean operation that can return 0 or 1. With `gcc 5.3.1`, your `f(-1)`, in the code you showed, returned `1`. One of us is very, very confused.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You do realize the question's been edited right?

Comment: @sleeptightpupper What does it have to do with this question? OP talks specifically about conversions, this is discussed separately.

Comment: Yes, @sleeptightpupper, and `f(-1)` is still doing a `==` comparison, as shown in this question.

Comment: "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
 bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined."

Comment: Aside from initially tagging this question C - which over complicated things, this is a very interesting post and a deserving of up votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is "no, this is not guaranteed" for both `f` and `g`.

Here is what the standard says about it:

> ### 4.7 Integral conversions
>
> 2. If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>      integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s
>      complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). — end note ]
> 3. If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Section 2 talks about function `g`. The cast of `x` to `unsigned` can cause change of representation on systems that do not use two's complement representation, so converting the number back may get you a different value.

Section 3 talks about function `f`. When the number is outside `signed int`'s range, the result is implementation-defined, so one is not allowed to make any claims about the result of converting it back to unsigned.