# Threshold an absolute value

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, micro-optimization

I have the following function:

```
char f1( int a, unsigned b ) { return abs(a) <= b; }
```

For execution speed, I want to rewrite it as follows:

```
char f2( int a, unsigned b ) { return (unsigned)(a+b) <= 2*b; } // redundant cast
```

Or alternatively with this signature that could have subtle implications even for non-negative `b`:

```
char f3( int a, int b )      { return (unsigned)(a+b) <= 2*b; }
```

Both of these alternatives work under a simple test on one platform, but I need it to portable.  Assuming non-negative `b` and no risk of overflow, is this a valid optimization for typical hardware and C compilers?  Is it also valid for C++?

---

*Note: As C++ on gcc 4.8 x86_64 with `-O3`, `f1()` uses 6 machine instructions and `f2()` uses 4.  The instructions for `f3()` are identical to those for `f2()`.  Also of interest: if `b` is given as a literal, both functions compile to 3 instructions that directly map to the operations specified in `f2()`.*

Comment: What part of this do you suspect is undefined behavior and why?

Comment: @NathanOliver: The cast to `unsigned` may reinterpret the bits.

Comment: Why cast to unsigned if the result can be negative?

Comment: Why do you think this implementation would be more optimized? Did you check what the compiler emits acually?

Comment: That cast is completely superfluous anyway.

Comment: @nobar It does not reinterpret any bits, it yields the representative of the casted number's equivalence class that fits into the range of `unsigned`. (Well, it might do that by reinterpreting bits, but you need not care about that.)

Comment: In the second case that cast may result in a huge number if the sum turns out to be negative, and this function will most likely return a `1` when it should actually be a zero.

Comment: @EugeneSh. @T.C.: Without the cast, it doesn't work correctly.  Negative numbers are mapped into the high-end of positive values -- which are above the `b` threshold.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The bottom part of my question addresses your comment directly.

Comment: @nobar If you see a difference without the cast, I would like to see a MCVE for that. `a` gets promoted to `unsigned` before the addition is performed anyways, and the result is an `unsigned` again. (At least in C++, but afaik that holds in C too.)

Comment: Did you try `return ((a<0) ? (a<=b) : (-a<=b));` ?

Comment: @dbush: Just tested your suggestion (with fix to `a>0`).  This produces 5 instructions of which one is a branch (that I would like to avoid).

Comment: `a*a <= b*b` - no branches..Overflow danger, though

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I made a mistake here due to testing multiple scenarios.  The cast *was* superfluous as this was originally posted because it is implicit based on the type of `b` being `unsigned`.  I should have left `b` as type `int`, and will make that edit now.

Comment: Did you check that the 6 instruction are actually slower than the 4 instructions? That's not always the case.

Comment: @rjp: Good point.  But the instruction counts given here are only for the sake of interest.  I want to give the formula that is generally simplest in order to help the compiler.  Real testing on my deeply embedded platform will come later.

Comment: The two functions don't return the same values. http://ideone.com/ahbzMk

Comment: @kfsone: `b` is meant to always be non-negative.

Comment: Then it should be `char f2(int a, unsigned int b) { return unsigned(a) + b <= 2*b;}`.

Comment: That's not valid C.

Comment: Language lawyering is hard :).  I will revert and expand the question.  In my mind, the exact way that I specified the function isn't the interesting thing -- but rather it's the idea of using a wraparound in this way.  So an answer would be fine if it noted a slightly different way to write the function as long as the wraparound concern was addressed.

Comment: The answers are confusing because you changed the question after you got two answers.

Comment: "is this a valid optimization for typical hardware and C compilers?" and `unsigned(a+b)` are confusing  as that code does not compile in C.

Comment: @PSkocik Unclear, what is the usefulness of `int a; ... (int)((unsigned int)a)`? Is not the result typically `a`?

Comment: @rjp: I agree it's sloppy and a bad idea to just talk about instruction counts for micro-optimizations like this.  But in this case, the instructions in question are all cheap (according to the compiler output: https://godbolt.org/g/v9XcyE), and if anything the version with more instructions uses a more expensive instruction.  (`sar` can't run on as many execution ports on Intel SnB-family CPUs.)  Two independent `add`s are cheaper than `mov` / `sar` / `xor` / `sub`.  clang uses mov/neg/cmov, which is still more expensive (especially on pre-Broadwell).  (See the x86 tag wiki)

Comment: Suggest `inline bool f2(int a, int b) { return a+b <= 2u * b; }`  (`bool` and `2u`)

Comment: And BTW, the original `_Bool f2_unsigned( int a, unsigned b ) { return (unsigned)(a+b)<=2*b; }` compiles to identical x86-64 code as the updated `_Bool f2_signed( int a, int b ) { return (unsigned)(a+b)<=2*b; }`.  https://godbolt.org/g/3MdK8o (also including chux's version).  (I assume you'd only use this as an inline function, so using `_Bool` to indicate to the caller that the return value is guaranteed to be a zero or one, not just any non-zero value doesn't gain anything.)  `_Bool` is a C99 built-in type; `#include <stdbool.h>` for the typedef for `bool`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes  Any particular reason/need for the `(unsigned)` cast?  `_Bool f2_unsigned( int a, unsigned b ) { return a+b <= 2*b; }` looks sufficient.

Comment: @chux: no.  Those are the OP's code, not my suggestion.  Just pointing out that the controversial edit that changes the question from a language lawyer perspective doesn't change the asm for gcc targeting x86, for whatever that's worth.  (And no, that doesn't mean it's necessarily safe or the same after inlining).  Your `2*b` or `2u * b` code compiles to the same good code as the OP's more efficient possibly-unsafe version.

Comment: @chux: Yes, thanks.  Using `2u` does resolve a "sign-compare" warning in my `f3()`.

Comment: Oops, update: making `b` signed does change the asm for `f1`, but not for `f2`.  This is because `abs(int)` still returns `int`, so `f1(int, int)` does a signed compare (`setle` instead of `setbe`), like `f3`.  [All versions on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/bOZsa1).

Comment: Have you consider a macro? `#define F4(a,b) ((unsigned)((a)+(b)) <= 2u*(b))`?

Comment: @chux: I'm assuming that the functions would be inlined by the compiler -- but if not, I would probably use a macro like the one you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the original code with signature

```
char f2( int a, unsigned b );
```

this contains the expression

```
a + b
```

Since one of these operands has a signed and the other an (corresponding) unsigned integer type (thus they have the same "integer conversion rank"), then - following the "Usual arithmetic conversions" (§ 6.3.1.8) - the operand with signed integer type is converted to the unsigned type of the other operand.

Conversion to an unsigned integer type is well defined, even if the value in question cannot be represented by the new type:

> [..] if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type. 60
>
> § 6.3.1.3/2

*Footnote 60 just says that the described arithmetic works with the mathematical value, not the typed one.*

Now, with the updated code

```
char f2_updated( int a, int b ); // called f3 in the question
```

things would look different. But since `b` is assumed to be non-negative, and assuming that `INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX` you can convert `b` to an `unsigned` without fearing it to have a different mathematical value afterwards. Thus you could write

```
char f2_updated( int a, int b ) {
  return f2(a, (unsigned)b); // cast unnecessary but to make it clear
}
```

Looking again at `f2` the expression `2*b` further limits the allowed range of `b` to be not larger than `UINT_MAX/2` (otherwise the mathematical result would be wrong).
So as long as you stay within these bounds, every thing is fine.

*Note: Unsigned types do not overflow, they "wrap" according to modular arithmetic.*

*Quotes from N1570 (a C11 working draft)*

---

A final remark:

IMO the only really reasonable choice to write this function is as

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
bool abs_bounded(int value, unsigned bound) {
  assert(bound <= (UINT_MAX / 2));
  /* NOTE: Casting to unsigned makes the implicit conversion that
           otherwise would happen explicit. */
  return ((unsigned)value + bound) <= (2 * bound);
}
```

Using a signed type for the `bound` does not make much sense, because the absolute of a value cannot be less than a negative number. `abs_bounded(value, something_negative)` would be always false. If there's the possibility of a negative bound, then I'd catch this outside of this function (otherwise it does "too much"), like:

```
int some_bound;
// ...
if ((some_bound >= 0) && abs_bounded(my_value, some_bound)) {
  // yeeeha
}
```

Comment: Arr ... that edit changing the b type to a signed integer came while I wrote the answer.

Comment: I really want to roll it back as it makes this answer and all of the comments pointless.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The comments noted that the cast was superfluous, but that didn't affect the point of the question.

Comment: @nobar: The cast was superfluous because it applied *after* promotion happened while evaluating `a+b`.  Changing `b`'s type *does* have an effect.  Read carefully what people are saying about how promotion happens when a binary operator has two operands of different types.

Comment: @nobar The edit changes the behavior of the entire code block as unsigned integer overflow is well defined.  Now that you do not have that you have a different question.

Comment: @EOF I tend to disagree: " — The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any." Equal rank means conversion to unsigned.

Comment: @EOF No problem, I had to look it up myself ^^ I reworded it to be hopefully less hand waving but still concise.

Comment: "Using a signed type .. does not make much sense" -- I think this question demonstrated that using `unsigned` types is generally a bad idea.  Look at the confusion it caused.  I actually only did it for documentation purposes -- because it was more concise than adding `assert(bound>=0)`, but it turned out to be a mistake.  In my opinion, [the "usual arithmetic conversions" are not sensible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38861423/86967) if you assume that arithmetic is more likely to involve negative values than to overflow signed values.

Comment: @nobar This question demonstrated that editing the question (or not posting the actual code one is working on in the first place) may indeed cause lot's of confusion ;) But I agree that the conversions are confusing. Banning `unsigned` is a far too drastic move IMO, though.

Answer (score 2):

To determine if the 2 expressions are equivalent for your purpose, you must study the domain of definition:

- `abs(a) <= b` is defined for all values of `int a` and `unsigned b`, with just one special case for `a = INT_MIN;`. On 2s complement architectures, `abs(INT_MIN)` is not defined but most likely evaluates to `INT_MIN`, which converted to `unsigned` as required for the `<=` with an `unsigned` value, yields the correct value.
- `(unsigned)(a+b) <= 2*b` may produce a different result for `b > UINT_MAX/2`.  For example, it will evaluate to false for `a = 1` and `b = UINT_MAX/2+1`. There might be more cases where you alternate formula gives an incorrect result.

**EDIT:** OK, the question was edited... and `b` is now an `int`.

Note that `a+b` invokes undefined behavior in case of overflow and the same for `2*b`.  So you make the assumption that neither `a+b` nor `2*b` overflow.  Furthermore, if `b` is negative, you little trick does not work.

If `a` is in the range `-INT_MAX/2..INT_MAX/2` and `b` in the range `0..INT_MAX/2`, it seems to function as expected.  The behavior is identical in C and C++.

Whether it is an optimization depends completely on the compiler, command line options, hardware capabilities, surrounding code, inlining, etc.  You already address this part and tell us that you shave one or two instructions... Just remember that this kind of micro-optimization is not absolute.  Even counting instructions does not necessarily help find the **best** performance.  Did you perform some benchmarks to measure if this *optimization* is worthwhile? Is the difference even measurable?

Micro-optimizing such a piece of code is self-defeating: it makes the code less readable and potentially incorrect. `b` might not be negative in the current version, but if the next maintainer changes that, he/she might not see the potential implications.

Comment: This answer seems to address only the boundary issues.  I attempted to explicitly exclude these by saying "no risk of overflow".

Comment: @nobar: you only did so after I pointed them out.  Modifying the question in a way that makes the answers irrelevant should only be done with EDIT: paragraphs.  I answered the **valid** part of the question and hinted as to when it is **invalid**. See my updated answer for the **optimization** part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

As OP wants fast and portable code (and `b` is positive), it *first* makes sense to code safely:

```
// return abs(a) <= b;
inline bool f1_safe(int a, unsigned b ) { 
  return (a >= 0 && a <= b) || (a < 0 && 0u - a <= b);
}
```

This works for **all** `a,b` (assuming `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX`).  Next, compare alternatives using an *optimized* compile (let the compiler do what it does best).

---

The following slight variation on OP's code will work in C/C++ but risks portability issues unless "Assuming non-negative b and no risk of overflow" can be certain on **all** target machines.

```
bool f2(int a, unsigned b) { return a+b <= b*2; }
```

In the end, OP goal of fast and portable code may find code the works optimally for the select platform, but not with others - such is micro-optimization.

Comment: To make no `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX` assumption, use `return (a >= 0 && a <= b) || (b && a < 0 && -1 - a <= b-1) || (b==0 && a== 0);`  If `b` is a constant, much code will optimize out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is portable to compliant platforms.  The conversion from signed to unsigned is well defined:

- [Conversion between signed integer and unsigned integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37450336/86967)
- [int to unsigned int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4975340/86967)
- [Signed to unsigned conversion in C - is it always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50605)

The description in the C spec is a bit contrived:

> if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly
>   adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be
>   represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new
>   type.

The [C++ spec](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#integral-2) addresses the same conversion in a more sensible way:

> In a two's complement representation, this conversion is conceptual
>   and there is no change in the bit pattern

---

In the question, `f2()` and `f3()` achieve the same results in a *slightly* different way.

- In `f2()` the presence of the `unsigned` operand causes a conversion of the `signed` operand as required [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#11) for C++.  The unsigned addition may-or-may-not then result in a wrap-around past zero, which is also well defined [citation needed].
- In `f3()` the addition occurs in signed representation with no trickiness, and then the result is (explicitly) converted to unsigned.  So  this is slightly simpler than `f2()` (and also more clear).

In both cases, the you end up with the same unsigned representation of the sum, which can then be compared (as unsigned) to `2*b`.  And the *trick* of treating a signed value as an unsigned type allows you to check a two-sided range with only a single comparison.  Note also that this is a bit more flexible than using the `abs()` function since the trick doesn't require that the range be centered around zero.

---

### Commentary on the "usual arithmetic conversions"

I think this question demonstrated that using unsigned types is generally a bad idea. Look at the confusion it caused here.

It can be tempting to use `unsigned` for documentation purposes (or to take advantage of the shifted value range), but due to the conversion rules, this may tend to be a mistake. In my opinion, the "usual arithmetic conversions" are not sensible if you assume that arithmetic is more likely to involve negative values than to overflow signed values.

I asked this followup question to clarify the point: [mixed-sign integer math depends on variable size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38861423/86967).  One new thing that I have learned is that mixed-sign operations are *not* generally portable because the conversion type will [depend on the size relative to that of `int`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#1).

In summary: *Using type declarations or casts to perform unsigned operations is a low-level coding style that should be approached with the requisite caution.*

Comment: You could be more specific and say "two's complement platforms", not just "compliant platforms", if that's the requirement.  That latter is like saying "it works on platforms where it works".  What happens when you cast a negative `int` to unsigned on a one's complement or sign/magnitude machine?  And is this code still safe on such a machine?  It's still useful as long as it's free of possible signed overflows or other UB, but it would be interesting to know if it's safe in general, or exactly where it would go wrong on non-two's complement C implementations.

Comment: @PeterCordes: By "compliant", I meant "language-standard compliant".  I think the standard pretty-much implies two's complement, without out-right requiring it.  As I understand it, weird hardware would have to use workarounds to achieve language compliance.  Workarounds like "repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented...".

Comment: Yeah, I haven't thought through the implications of that wording either, but I'm not sure it's very expensive.  It probably takes at most one branch to implement that wording, and casts from unsigned to int don't happen all the time.  It's disappointing the standard refuses to actually standardize two's complement for anything other than atomic `int`, or stuff like arithmetic right shift of signed `int`.  The standard is too weak for its own good; I like what I've seen of Rust so far (esp. built-in popcnt and stuff), but haven't really done anything with it.

Comment: The version which adds two `int` values without casting or coercing either to an unsigned type first will invoke UB for some combinations of operands.  Even thought the C89 rationale implies an intention that when code performs arithmetic on two int values and immediately converts the result to an unsigned type which is not larger than "int", silent-wraparound two's-complement implementations should behave as though the operation was performed on unsigned values (since there's no defined case where it wouldn't) some compilers use integer overflow even in such cases as an excuse for wackiness.

Comment: One of the problems faced by the authors of C89 was the fact that some implementations promoted short unsigned types to int, while others promoted to unsigned.  It's too bad C89 didn't resolve this issue by defining qualifiers to distinguish e.g. 16-bit types that represent numbers 0-65535 from 16-bit types that represent mod-65536 equivalence classes.  Unqualified unsigned types could then behave in Implementation-defined fashion, while code wanting numbers or modular arithmetic could specify what it wanted.

Comment: @supercat: I'm assuming you're talking about signed integer overflow when you mention UB.  I'm not concerned about that here.  I figure UB on signed integer overflow is a reasonable outcome.  It's up to the programmer to make sure the type is large enough for the math.

Comment: @nobar: When the C Standard was written, and for a long time after, the majority of (e.g. 16-bit) compilers would have processed f3(16384,24576) by performing an addition that yields either 40960 or -24576 and a multiplication that yields either 49152 or -16384.  It would then convert both results to unsigned (yielding 40960 and 49152, respectively), and performed the comparison.  Recently, however, it has become fashionable for compilers to treat integer overflow--even in formerly-benign situations like the above--in ways that can cause arbitrary side-effects on other code.

Comment: Related: [Why does C++ standard specify signed integer be cast to unsigned in binary operations with mixed signedness?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43336218/86967)

Comment: Whether or not these, and related, operations are "undefined behavior" is, um, complicated: [signed overflow is UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17205195/86967), [signed overflow is UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16188263/86967).  When talking about UB, it is necessary to be precise about the details of the operation.

Comment: For shift-left it is even more confusing (or version dependent): https://stackoverflow.com/q/3784996

Comment: Is this undefined behavior? [unsigned long cannot hold the correct number over 2,147,483,647](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60455240/86967)