# mixed-sign integer math depends on variable size

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Functions `g1()` and `g2()` have identical logic, but the input types have different sizes.  Why do they return different results for negative sums?

```
/*BINFMTCXX: -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++11
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char g1( int32_t a, uint32_t b ) { return a+b<9; } // fails when a+b is negative
char g2( int16_t a, uint16_t b ) { return a+b<9; } // works if no overflow

int main()
   {

   for ( int a=-2, b=0; a<=2; a++ )
      {
      fprintf(stderr,"a=%+d, b=%d, g1=%+d, g2=%+d %s\n", a, b, g1(a,b), g2(a,b), g1(a,b)==g2(a,b)?"":"!" );
      }

   return 0;
   }
```

When I run it, it shows that `g1()` fails when `a+b` is negative:

```
$ ./mixed_sign_math_per_size.cpp
a=-2, b=0, g1=+0, g2=+1 !
a=-1, b=0, g1=+0, g2=+1 !
a=+0, b=0, g1=+1, g2=+1 
a=+1, b=0, g1=+1, g2=+1 
a=+2, b=0, g1=+1, g2=+1
```

The results are the same in C and C++.

Comment: *but the input types have different sizes.* -- Don't you think what is more important is that the types are signed / unsigned rather than the size of these types?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes, the input types have mixed sign.  However, this is not a difference between `g1()` and `g2()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280663/in-a-c-expression-where-unsigned-int-and-signed-int-are-present-which-type-will to explain `g1`, the negative number is converted to a very large unsigned number. For `g2`, both are converted to `int` which has enough range to handle both inputs without loss.

Comment: I don't know why but: in g1() `decltype(a+b)` is unsigned; in g2() `decltype(a+b)` is signed.   Try `decltype(a+b) r = a+b; return r<9;` and debug it.

Comment: FWIW: The code in the dup question would likely trigger compiler warnings, whereas my code did not (in either C or C++).  Nevertheless, the answers are closely related -- even though that question does not specify C++.

Answer (score 3):

As a result of the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#11), both `a` and `b` in `g2`'s body are promoted to `int`, which is why that function works perfectly well.

For `g1`, because (`u`)`int32_t` does not have a rank less than that of `int`, no promotion occurs, and the very last bullet point (11.5.5) applies. Both operands are converted to the unsigned type, which - in `a`'s case - causes an underflow, producing a value much greater than 9. Hence `g1` returned `1` (`true`).

Comment: I can't figure out what you are referencing as "10.5.5".  Your link was to 5.11.

Comment: @nobar My bad, I was looking at a local, outdated draft. (11.5.5)  is the fifth bullet point of the fifth bullet point in paragraph 11.

Comment: This is IMO a bit unclear: `a` and `b` are not converted due to the "usual arithmetic conversion" but due to "integer promotion" (which happens first). At least that'd be my understanding of the exact wording in the standard.

Comment: @DanielJour My interpretation is that promotion is only applied because the fifth top-level bullet point applies.

Comment: @Columbo Yes, that makes more sense than my interpretation.